# could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: mysql, sqldeveloper

Есть MySql, есть oracle sql developer. Качаю jtds-1.2.5.jar и mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin-g.jar. В tools->preferences->database->third party jdbc drivers выбираю mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin-g.jar. Пытаюсь создать соединение с msql, нажимаю Test. Вопрос, почему выдает это - could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.driver?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема лечится следующим образом: с этого сайта https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/ нужно скачать драйвер версии 5.1, с этим драйвером коннект работает.